# Removing lines of text that match strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, yaml-front-matter

I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution to remove lines of text that match keywords in an arrays of strings. A typical application would be, for instance, YAML frontmatter, which we want to filter of non applicable properties.

Let' say we have a string like this:

```js
let str = `
up: some text here
archetype: "[[Atlas]]"
related: 
status: 
type: 
uuid: '202403041152'
`
```

I am using backticks to enter the string to make it easier to enter one line of text at a time.

We want to exclude some properties from the frontmatter string entering the exclusions in an array.

```js
const exclude = ["status", "type", ]
```

How do we remove the keywords in the array `exclude` from the multi-line string?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the most consistent result is when we convert each line of the YAML string to an array of strings, and then iterate through `exclude` and the array to apply the regex to each line.

A function to remove the whole line in `str` that are listed in the `exclude` array:

```js
function removeWhitespace(txt) {
    return txt
        .filter(function(entry) { return entry.trim() != '' });
}
function removeExcludedKeys(str, exclude) {
    let strA = str.split("\n")    // convert to array
    strA = removeWhitespace(strA) // remove white spaces
    exclude.forEach(ex => {
        let regex = RegExp("\\b" + ex + ".*","gi")
        strA = strA.map(p => p.replace(regex, '')) });
    return removeWhitespace(strA).join("\n") 
}
```

Called with:

```js
console.log(removeExcludedKeys(str, exclude))
```

Output as follows:

```
up: some text here
archetype: "[[Atlas]]"
related:
uuid: '202403041152'
```

I came up with this solution when I was receiving false positives whenever I wanted to remove `type`, and unintentionally it was removing the property `archetype`. The function `removeWhitespace` is necessary to remove whitespaces caused when entering the string between backticks, and also removing the whitespaces in the resulting array.

Comment: perhaps you should use a real YAML parser instead for more reliable results?

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it. But my use is "one-off". For the YAML parser, I would have to install the corresponding libraries. It's too much for such a simple use. Additionally, it is a good exercise while I learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

@Yogi,
adding a `trim()` to remove the extra whitespace at the top of the resulting string.

```
let textContent = `
up: some text here
archetype: "[[Atlas]]"
related: 
status: 
type: 
uuid: '202403041152'
`

const exclude = ["status", "type", "related"]

// generate regex and remove keys
// regex = (^\s*key$\n)|...

const removeExcludedKeys = (str = '', exclude = []) => 
str.replace(new RegExp( exclude.map(capture => 
`(^\\s*${capture}:.*$\\n)`).join('|'), 'gmiu'), '').trim()

console.log(removeExcludedKeys(textContent, exclude))
```

**Result:**

```
up: some text here
archetype: "[[Atlas]]"
uuid: '202403041152'
```

I tried also to replace the regex to something that could be defined outside the function but I was unsuccessful. Something like:

```
let regex = "`(^\\s*${capture}:.*$\\n)`"
```